# Objective - c - NSMutableArray Array of Arrays

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, xcode

I am developing an iphone app and I was wondering the following:

How do I initialise an NSMutableArray of NSMutableArrays to a certain size?

Sorry for the noob question

Answer (score 11):

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   NSMutableArray *innerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];

   [array addObject:innerArray];
}
```

Comment: Note that initWithCapacity: is just setting an initial capacity.  The array can continue to grow as much as you like (it's an optimization tool)

Comment: For someone that's new I don't think that's obvious.  C arrays are certainly mutable and certainly don't have built-in expansion of available space

Answer (score 3):

You don't set a maximum size.  You just keep addObject:'ing to them

Comment: Exactly, NSMutableArray don't need initWithCapacity. Never.